# Netty handlerRemoved and handlerAdded method

Tags: java, netty

Netty  when is handlerRemoved and handlerAddedmethod(of ChannelInboundHandler) invoked?And how is it diffrent from ChannelActive and Inactive

Comment: This sounds more like a question to look up in the netty docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the java docs... handlerAdded(...) is called when the handler is added to the pipeline and handlerRemoved(...) after it is removed.